# Can't return wanting type of data using Cython

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I want to build a function that can return the most common permutation of six "R" letters plus six "B" letters, the list may looks like this:

```
a = ['R'] * 6 + ['B'] * 6
random.shuffle(a)
shuffle = ''.join(a)
shuffle
```

Output: 'BRBRRRBBRBBR'

I want to write a loop of this function to simulate the most common distribution of these strings. I did write a for loop with python and it did work, but after I import cython to accelerate this function, something goes wrong, here is the code:

```
'''Python Code'''
import random
def random_loop_py(times):
    a = ['R'] * 6 + ['B'] * 6
    count = {}
    for i in range(times):
        random.shuffle(a)
        shuffle = ''.join(a)
        if shuffle in count.keys():
            count[shuffle] += 1
        else:
            count[shuffle] = 1
    return count
%timeit random_loop_py(100000)

'''Cython Code'''
    %load_ext cython
    %%cython
    import random
    cpdef void random_loop(int size):
        a = ['R'] * 6 + ['B'] * 6
        count = {}
        for i in range(size):
            random.shuffle(a)
            shuffle = ''.join(a)
            if shuffle in count.keys():
                count[shuffle] += 1
            else:
                count[shuffle] = 1
        return count.values()
```

And Error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        shuffle = ''.join(a)
        if shuffle in count.keys():
            count[shuffle] += 1
        else:
            count[shuffle] = 1
    return count.keys()
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/lee_excited/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_e70ad62499224c5d4fd4e23d6dcb9e49.pyx:12:21: Return with value in void function
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-a09f2e5d5e69> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('cython', '', "import random\ncpdef void random_loop(int size):\n    a = ['R'] * 6 + ['B'] * 6\n    count = {}\n    for i in range(size):\n        random.shuffle(a)\n        shuffle = ''.join(a)\n        if shuffle in count.keys():\n            count[shuffle] += 1\n        else:\n            count[shuffle] = 1\n    return count.keys()\n")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2321             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2322             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2323                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2324             return result
   2325 

<decorator-gen-127> in cython(self, line, cell)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/IpythonMagic.py in cython(self, line, cell)
    323         if need_cythonize:
    324             extensions = self._cythonize(module_name, code, lib_dir, args, quiet=args.quiet)
--> 325             assert len(extensions) == 1
    326             extension = extensions[0]
    327             self._code_cache[key] = module_name

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

What kind of data should I return to accelerate my simulation, please?

Comment: Please, post your code and exceptions as text.

Comment: OK, I have added the code.

Comment: Remove the screenshots entirely. Including the output.

Comment: OK, deleted and rearranged issue structure.

Comment: OK, deleted and rearranged issue structure. @MadPhysicist

Comment: Just to be clear, are you doing this to find non-uniformities in the way random.shuffle works?

Answer (score 0):

Your function has a `void` return type:

```
cpdef void random_loop(int size):
    ...
    return count.values()
```

Consequently, you are not supposed to return anything from it, and the exception message is very clear on that. Change the return type to `list`:

```
cpdef list random_loop(int size):
    ...
    return list(count.values())
```

P.S.

Your function is not very Cython-friendly: I don't think you will get significant performance improvements.

**Update**

I can't reproduce your error after the fix

```
In [9]: %%cython
   ...: import random
   ...: cpdef list random_loop(int size):
   ...:     a = ['R'] * 6 + ['B'] * 6
   ...:     count = {}
   ...:     for i in range(size):
   ...:         random.shuffle(a)
   ...:         shuffle = ''.join(a)
   ...:         if shuffle in count.keys():
   ...:             count[shuffle] += 1
   ...:         else:
   ...:             count[shuffle] = 1
   ...:     return list(count.values())
   ...: 

In [10]: random_loop(10)
Out[10]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

As you can see, it compiles perfectly fine.

Comment: Tried, still Error /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: @WeizheLi You should clarify whether that is the same error or a new one

Comment: Actually I tried print(count.values()) and it works, about 10 times acceleration, so I tried to directly return the dict, but something went wrong. sad.

Comment: @WeizheLi I can't reproduce your error. See the update

Comment: Maybe because my IDLE is Jupyter 

Comment: @WeizheLi Jupyter is no different from iPython (which I'm using here).

Comment: Strange, let me copy yours.

Comment: Still doesn't work, may I ask which version of Python and Cython you are using?

Comment: Mine: Python 3.6.6 final 0, Cython 0.29

Comment: @WeizheLi Python 3.6.5, Cython 0.28.2. There should be no difference. Are you really copying my code from the **Update** block?

Comment: Worked, same code, different output, confusing. But thank you very much. XD

Comment: Yes, millions of thanks. And it doesn't get significant performance improvements as you said, while the print function did. But I don't know why due to my poor coding skill

Comment: @WeizheLi you can accept the answer, if it has resolved your issue.